# Como verificar se há um elemento em uma lista em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Estou tentando fazer um algoritmo em Python para verificar se há um elemento em determinada lista. Se sim, o programa irá printar na tela, se não, irá adicionar um novo elemento na lista.

Minha intenção é criar uma lista com 4 elementos e adicionar mais 6. Eu irei printar os elementos contidos nela e caso nao encontre mais elementos (a partir do 4º laço), passe a adicionar o que eu quero.

Fiz o código assim:

```
nomes = ['A', 'B','C','D','E']
i=0
for x in range(10):
    if : #precisoSaberQualCondiçãoColocarAqui
         print(x)
    else:
        nomes.append(i)
        i+=1
print(nomes)
```

Comment: 1 in [1,2,3] # True. Use o comando `in`. Ele verifica se há algo na lista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando `in`:

```
1 in [1,2,3] # True
7 in [1,2,3] # False
```

No caso do `if`:

```
if x in nomes:
   print(x)
```

Comment: Resolveu certinho!