# Como dar uma mesma resposta a diferentes possíveis entradas do usuário

Tags: python

Fiz este código para tentar obter diferentes tipos de opções de resposta do usuário, por exemplo, se eu responder "bom dia" ou "BOM DIA" em ambos posso obter a mesma saída:

```
print('Olá! Sou Maria, fale comigo!')
maria = input()
if maria == ['bom dia', 'BOM DIA', 'Bom dia', 'bom Dia']:
    print('Bom dia! Como você está?')
```

Mas o código funciona sem imprimir nada. Não entendi o porquê, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Faça `if maria in [...]`

Comment: Mas poderia fazer `if maria.lower() == 'bom dia'` e assim considerar qualquer variação de maiúsculas e minúsculas do sem exemplo, até, por exemplo, `BOM dia`, que não existe na lista.

Comment: hmmm beleza, mas em outro caso q eu quero colocar outras possibilidades de resposta, por exemplo:
Maria -> Como você está?
Você -> Estou bem ou Bem ou To de boa
como eu poderia escrever?

Comment: Pode fazer uma combinação dos dois...

Comment: Quem está negativando não acha bom comentar a motivação do -1? Qual o problema com a pergunta? É realmente razoável esperar que qualquer nova pessoa na programação saiba _debugar_ um comportamento “errado“ que falha silenciosamente?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Python: Como verificar se há um elemento em uma lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365338/python-como-verificar-se-h%c3%a1-um-elemento-em-uma-lista)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pode utilizar o comparador de igualdade (`==`) para verificar se uma lista contém determinado elemento. Nesse caso, você está comparando a lista com um valor que nem sequer é do tipo lista. Isso sempre dará falso a não ser que você compare duas listas iguais. [Leitura complementar.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38106/69296)

O erro do seu código está aqui:

> ```
> if maria == ['bom dia', 'BOM DIA', 'Bom dia', 'bom Dia']:
> ```

Para isso você pode utilizar o operador `in`, assim:

> ```
> if maria in ['bom dia', 'BOM DIA', 'Bom dia', 'bom Dia']:
> ```

Mas repare que sua lista de respostas esperadas tem a mesma resposta. A diferença encontra-se apenas na caixa de cada uma das letras. Nesse sentido, uma alternativa melhor é converter tudo para caixa baixa e fazer somente uma comparação. Assim:

```
if maria.lower() == 'bom dia':
```

No entanto, se existirem respostas que variam não somente em relação à caixa, será necessário comparar a resposta a uma série de valores pré-definidos.

Contudo, utilizar uma lista pode não ser sempre uma boa ideia para esse tipo de coisa, uma vez que o método `in` faz buscas lineares. Uma alternativa melhor é utilizar um [*set*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), que [faz buscas, em média, em tempo constante](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). O operador `in` também é utilizado. A diferença dá-se não pelo operador, mas sim pela estrutura de dados utilizada.

No fim, você teria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
print('Olá! Sou Maria, fale comigo!')

resp = input().lower()

# note o erro de digitação no segundo elemento, que também é visto como válido
if resp in {'bom dia', 'bon dia'}:
    print('Bom dia! Como você está?')
```

Repare que, ao contrário de listas, que são denotadas por colchetes, *sets* são denotados por chaves.

Claro que, para um conjunto pequeno de respostas, a diferença na eficiência é irrisória, mas conforme a quantidade de elementos a serem comparados aumenta, [a diferença pode ser grande](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/485192/69296).

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO AMIGO
deu certo
muito obrigado mesmo